# How to find number of streams that are using same component in RTC?

Tags: java, stream, rtc, ibm-rad

IN RTC source control, I am having a component named "`Article Component`".
I am using this component in multiple streams.

**Now, when I search for the component, how can I find all the streams associated with the component "`Article Component`"?**.

Am I having any option in RTC to find this?

Eg:

```
Component 1: Article1 Component
Component 2: Article2 Component

Stream 1: Article Development Stream 1
Stream 2: Article Development Stream 2
Stream 3: Article Development Stream 3
Stream 4: Article Development Stream 4
```

With:

- Stream 1 is using component-1 and component-2,
- Stream 2 is using component-1 only
- Stream 3 is using component-1 only,
- Stream 4 is using component-2 only.

Now when I search for `component1` i.e. `Article1` component, then I should be displayed the following result:

```
Article1 Component - Article Development Stream 1
Article1 Component - Article Development Stream 2
Article1 Component - Article Development Stream 3
```

Thanks,
Vijay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Than making use of the rtc api it is better to create a birt report for finding this. For this you can refer the creation of reports articles in jazz.net

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/96084/how-to-search-for-all-visible-streams-that-contains-a-certain-component), **there is a way to do this via API, but not through the clients**.

Through [Java API for instance](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/126780/using-rtc-api-how-to-get-stream-name-from-component-and-repository-name) (see [this article](https://jazz.net/library/article/1229) for getting it), using `IWorkspaceManager.findWorkspacesContainingComponent`:
This searches for all workspace/streams that contain the component. Something like this:

```
IWorkspaceSearchCriteria criteria = IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.FACTORY.newInstance();
criteria.setKind(IWorkspaceSearchCriteria.STREAMS);
IWorkspaceManager manager = SCMPlatform.getWorkspaceManager(repository);
List< IWorkspaceHandle > workspaces = manager.findWorkspacesContainingComponent(component, criteria,  Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```